# Conditional attributes and logic per product category

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions

Firstly, English is not my first language so i'm sorry if my grammar and the way i deliver this question is horrible. And i'm basically has no coding skill, so please help me with explain what is the code for and where i implant the code.

So i have a website, its had a features where customer could sell their design and attach them on product template on my site (*in simple way, it's technically same as **Teespring** site*).

So, for that, i make an "**add product**" pages for seller on **front-end** to upload and sells their products. i almost make it, but i'm stuck on some function that was to add a conditional *woo commerce* taxonomies value for specific product category.

I doesn't know what i need to do first, so i'm decide to coming here to ask a help

So, i want to make add product pages on **front-end** that was **on different pages for each category**. In example seller want to make a hoodie designs, so it was on make-products/hoodie. so in this pages, they only needs to add their designs and fill product name, prices, and description while when they submit it, automatically it has an output of product_cat is hoodie, than pa_ like hoodie sizes, hoodie colors, hoodie SEO description etc so its display perfectly on single product pages without seller need to add every details on their owns.

So, my question is, Where i need to start? is there any plugins i could use here? how to define that what category is on that pages/URL so it will has an output of that category? and how to set the custom attributes that automatically added when has specific category as an output? please explain what code i need to edit and explain what's that code use for. thanks for your help, sorry if my question is too hard to understand and i ask too much question. thank you.